# how to get value from json response in xamarin android?(user login purpose in android app)

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.android

c# code:-

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();

  HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);

  string result = await client.GetStringAsync(url);

 Console.WriteLine(result);
```

json respose(result):-

```
{
    "accountstab": [
        {
            "LoginType": "r",
            "RepId": 3368,
            "RepName": "Aachi's M",
            "RepUName": "aachis",
            "RepPwd": "aachis123",
            "WhlId": null,
            "RepLocalId": null,
            "WhoName": "Aachi's M",
            "WhoTin": "32661034",
            "WhoEmail": "hanee@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "LoginType": "r",
            "RepId": 3335,
            "RepName": "AL-NAJA M",
            "RepUName": "alnaja",
            "RepPwd": "chemmad",
            "WhlId": null,
            "RepLocalId": null,
            "WhoName": "AL-NAJA",
            "WhoTin": "7222075",
            "WhoEmail": "abbas@gmail.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

model class:

```
public class RootObject

    {
        public List<Accountstab> accountstab { get; set; }
    }
    public class Accountstab
    {
        public string LoginType { get; set; }
        public int RepId { get; set; }
        public string RepName { get; set; }
        public string RepUName { get; set; }
        public string RepPwd { get; set; }
        public int? WhlId { get; set; }
        public int? RepLocalId { get; set; }
        public string WhoName { get; set; }
        public string WhoTin { get; set; }
        public string WhoEmail { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i get values from Json object in Xamarin Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39770222/how-do-i-get-values-from-json-object-in-xamarin-form) or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38743280/deserialize-json-object-xamarin-android-c-sharp or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51530503/xamarin-json-deserialize or more complicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48407196/how-to-deserialize-json-with-json-net-and-xamarin-with-subtypes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if there is any problem with string value="null" in json , public string WhoTin { get; set; } this field are null is some records

The error of you json string is not caused by the null, it caused by the `'` in the json below.

```
"RepName": "Aachi's M", 
"WhoName": "Aachi's M",
```

The way you used to deserliaze the json data in Xamarin.forms is correct.

```
var jsondata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
```

When you change the `'` in json data, it would be okay.

```
"RepName": "Aachi s M" 
"WhoName": "Aachi s M",
```

[image]

Comment: Error:-'Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: <. Path '', line 3, position 0.'    json:-{"accountstab":[{"LoginType":"r","RepId":368,"RepName":"Aachis Medicines","RepUName":"aachis","RepPwd":"aachis123","WhlId":null,"RepLocalId":null,"WhoName":"Aachis Medicines","WhoTin":"32010661034","WhoEmail":"hanee@gmail.com"},{"LoginType":"r","RepId":354,"RepName":"Ajwa Medicals","RepUName":"mohammed","RepPwd":"koladi","WhlId":null,"RepLocalId":null,"WhoName":"Ajwa Medicals","WhoTin":"applied","WhoEmail":"koladi@yahoo.com"}]} please help @Wendy

Comment: I have check the json data you provided, no error with it. Please check it at runtime. I guess you get something else after json data.

Answer (score 2):

I can be done with `Newtonsoft.Json` dll from NuGet:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
// ... 
RootObject json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result);
```

Usage example:

```
foreach (var item in json.accountstab)
     Console.WriteLine(item.RepUName);
```

Output:

```
aachis
alnaja
```

Comment: Would you not flag this question as a duplicate rather than provide an answer? deserializing json is really common in Xamarin and there are loads of questions and answers on it

Comment: code:-RootObject  rootObject  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result);
            Console.WriteLine(rootObject.accountstab.Count);                                                                            Error :Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: <. Path '', line 3, position 0.'

Comment: var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
            string result = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            if(result != null)
            {
                JObject a = JObject.Parse(result);
                JArray rep = (JArray)a["accountstab"];
                IList<RootObject> rootobject = rep.ToObject<IList<RootObject>>();   }    how to get value of RepUname and Reppwd-for login purpose

Comment: Error:-    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: <. Path '', line 3, position 0.'  @Nehorai please help me

Comment: @Merloon I tested my code with the provided json and it worked fine for me, are you getting the error on the same provided json? try to put a breakpoint debuging your code

Comment: if there  is any problem with string value="null" in json ,                                               public string WhoTin { get; set; } this field are null is some records @Nehorai